# Translation of "primer" in the context of textbook

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, anglicismes

[Primer:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/primer)

> NOUN An elementary textbook that serves as an introduction to a
>   subject of study or is used for teaching children to read.
>
> ‘a first-year philosophy primer’

Webster, 1962:

> One of the definitions of primer (prim΄·er) is that it is a textbook
>   that gives the first principles of any subject.

Par exemple je veux interpréter :

> Continuum Mechanics Primer (voir: http://www.dmm.im.ufrj.br/~liu/Papers/MCURS.pdf)

Peut-on utiliser *primer* en français dans ce contexte ?

> Apprêt sur le mécanique des milieux continus

L'usage du mot *apprêt* dans ce contexte convient ou pas ?

Si oui, pourquoi Larousse et cnrtl n'en parle-il pas ?

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/appr%C3%AAt/4749

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/appr%C3%AAt

Comment: From the Oxford dictionary: *Primer: A cosmetic applied to the face before another product, intended to improve the coverage and lasting effect of the second product.*

Comment: @jlliagre I understand now that apprêt translates this sense but not the sense of elementary textbook. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already stated, *apprêt* doesn't match the right "primer" definition.

"Continuum Mechanics **Primer**" might be translated by :

> ***Initiation** à la mécanique des milieux continus*
>
> ***Introduction** à la mécanique des milieux continus*
>
> ***Bases** de la mécanique des milieux continus*

You might also venture :

> *La mécanique des milieux continus **pour les nuls** !*

;-)

Comment: Voici une situation difficile à choisir parmi les réponses:-)! Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Précis de la mécanique des milieux continus signifie la même chose ou pas ? Merci !

Comment: Oui. *Précis* est un peu démodé mais correspond très bien à la définition souhaitée. Il faut cependant enlever le *la* : *Précis de mécanique des milieux continus*.

Answer (score 3):

Possiblement aussi [*manuel élémentaire*, *abcédaire*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/primer/604034) (*alphabet primer*) (Larousse en ligne) ou [*introduction, notions élémentaires sur..., notions de..., l'abc de..., guide d'introduction*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=primer&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) voire peut-être *capsule* dans certains contextes (Termium) ou [*premiers cours de*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=10453795)... (GDT)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use dictionaries that don't provide context. Where did you get " *apprêt* "?

With a quick search on [word reference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/primer), you can see that "*apprêt*" refers to a base coat of paint, not the translation you want.

"*Primer*" in your sense would be "*premier livre*", or "*livre d'introduction*". There is no single word in French for that.

Comment: https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=en&text=appr%C3%AAt

Comment: Also my French-Greek dictionary gives among the translations one greek word that has exactly the meaning of primer.

Comment: @dimitris I don't understand your google translate link. "Apprêt" does translate to "primer" (because "primer means multiple things in English) but that's not the point.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. I thought that apprêt also translates primer in the sense of elementary textbook that serves as an intro. I was also misguided by me French-Greek dictionary.

Comment: If the document that we are talking about is not a book but a few pages document for the students, how should we translate, for instance, continuum mechanics primer in French ? Introduction à la mécanique des milieux continus n'interprète pas exactement le sens, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: @dimitris *Introduction à la mécanique des milieux continus* would work for a few pages document too.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci encore. Grâce à tous, j'ai bien compris le problème de l'interprétation et la solution de contournement :-)!

Comment: @dimitris Le mot  « fascicule » pourrait être utilisé pour donner à l'ouvrage sa juste importance : Fascicule d'introduction à la mécanique des milieux continus.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a deux façons courantes de traduire « primer » lorsque ce terme s'applique à un livre de texte autre que pour les enfants.

> manuel d'introduction, livre d'introduction

« Primer » n'est qu'un verbe en français. Cependant, Greg trouve les trace d'un anglicisme (qui doit être assez récent) et qui est employé dans le domaine de la [peinture d'intérieur](http://www.deco-solutions.com/conseils/maison/decoration-et-renovation/8050-choisir-son-primer-selon-le-support-de-peinture.html) pour signifier « première couche », c'est à dire couche de peinture avant la couche finale mais sur le support (ou enduit), s'il y en a un; selon Greg on donne au mot la  prononciation à l'anglaise « \pʁaj.mœʁ\ » ou la prononciation francisée « pri .mœʁ ».

D'après le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/primer) ce terme a trouvé d'autres usages (cométologie et construction)

Comment: L'anglicisme *primer* est parfois utilisé dans son sens anglais, prononcé à l'anglaise ou "francisé" par la prononciation "primeur". Un exemple [ici](http://www.deco-solutions.com/conseils/maison/decoration-et-renovation/8050-choisir-son-primer-selon-le-support-de-peinture.html)

Answer (score 0):

Complément aux excellentes réponses.

On peut aussi utiliser *précis*. Bien qu'il soit un démodé, correspond très bien à la définition souhaitée. On pourrait donc dire :

> Précis de mécanique des milieux continus.

(Merci @jlliagre pour la confirmation et la correction.)

L'anglicisme primer est parfois utilisé dans son sens anglais, prononcé à l'anglaise ou "francisé" par la prononciation "primeur". Un exemple [ici](http://www.deco-solutions.com/conseils/maison/decoration-et-renovation/8050-choisir-son-primer-selon-le-support-de-peinture.html).

(Merci @Greg pour ce commentaire.)