# Le mot « fascicule » : est-il courant ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, science

Dans les commentaires [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33042/translation-of-primer-in-the-context-of-textbook/33043#comment67822_33043) (merci @LPH) le mot fascicule est mentionné.
Je me demande si c'est un mot [courant](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fascicule%2Cpr%C3%A9cis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfascicule%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0) et si nous pouvons l'utiliser comme ci-dessous :

> Fascicule de mécanique appliquée.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Fascicule* qui n'est ni très courant ni inconnu mais commence à être assez démodé. Il ne semble pas très indiqué ici sauf s'il est prévu d'en publier plusieurs :

TLFi: [Fascicule](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fascicule)

> **a)** Ensemble de feuilles, de cahiers ou groupe de cahiers d'un ouvrage ou d'un périodique publié en plusieurs parties.
>   ...
>   **b)**  Ouvrage complet faisant partie d'une collection.

Voici un Ngram reprenant quelques suggestions de l'autre question qui montre que la popularité de fascicule a commencé à chuter il y a une soixantaine d'années :

[image]

Comment: La recherche au moyen de la commande « ctrl f » n'accède pas les commentaires non visibles ; il faut les déployer d'abord.

Comment: @LPH Oui, je l'ai vu. Merci.

Answer (score 2):

C'est un commentaire que j'ai fait ; le fascicule est une publication de la sorte suivante définie dans le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fascicule) ;

> Dans le domaine de l'éducation
>   a) Ensemble de feuilles, de cahiers ou groupe de cahiers d'un ouvrage ou d'un périodique publié en plusieurs parties. Publication par fascicules.
>  
>   b) Ouvrage complet faisant partie d'une collection.

Le type de livre discuté est un livre d'introduction (primer), donc, s'il est suivi par d'autres ouvrages qui développent le sujet, il peut être appelé un fascicule et même numéroté, les autres parties sont les fascicules suivants. Ce n'est pas un synonyme de « livre d'introduction » cependant ; ce terme, selon la première définition, signifie « partie » ; il peut entrer dans le titre en tant que second titre ; voici, par exemple, un titre dans lequel ce mot est utilisé ;

- La thermodynamique
  Fascicule 1 : Introduction à la thermodynamique

C'est un terme qui décrit la forme d'une publication et non le contenu, un peut comme « tome » ; il est beaucoup utilisé par les enseignants, en particulier ceux qui fournissent le support de cours en livret de petite taille qu'ils écrivent eux-mêmes ; un ouvrage sous forme de fascicules peut consister de polycopiés qui parfois sont publiés, plus tard, sous une forme ou une autre ; les fascicules peuvent être rassemblés en un livre unique par exemple.

Je ne crois pas que le mot soit utilisé dans le titre lui-même, c'est à dire la partie principale du titre, mais je ne peux pas l'affirmer. Aussi, il n'est pas nécessaire que le mot paraisse dans le sous-titre pour qu'une telle partie d'un ouvrage soit appelée un fascicule. Cependant, il est possible de citer les parties de l'ouvrage en spécifiant le mot « fascicule » ;

- fascicule  d'introduction à la thermodynamique